# how to permanently override android soft keys behaviour and display through

Tags: android

I am relatively new to android and want to create an application that permanently overrides androids basic softkey behaviour and view (for devices with soft keys).

Some functionalities I want to implement are changing the size of the softkeys window at the bottom, change its images, and possibly change its functionality.

For example, the user can set the size to of the softkey to be "large", "medium" or "small". And I can change the functionality of the back button to open say a particular application instead of going "back".

I'm basically looking for a high level answer as to how to do this, a basic direction of what I should read/study in order to be able to accomplish this. I realise this may require root access.

Please note that I want this behaviour to change not only in my application but I want the effect to exist on all applications. If this requires the application to be running atleast at the backend, that is fine.

After doing some decent amount of search, it seems I will have to make changes in the systemUI.apk, or possibly get its source code and modify it. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question is too vague to be usefully answered.  different types of problems have different types of solutions.

Comment: thanks j__m, I changed it to explain more precisely what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think even root is going to be enough for the type of changes you are describing.  You're going to need to edit the Android source code and build your own system image.

Comment: this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nowto.wtf.softkeys does something of the sort. basically it displays a permanent semi-transparent button (no matter where you are) and when clicked, the softkeys are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't override system resources because they are part of the system image.

What you are looking for is called `Home Application` which can be developed like any other android app *no need for root* , you can find an example for it in your sdk samples. 
[Home Sample Application](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/Home/index.html).

your app would be responsible to have UI components to send the user to all of the phone functionalities which includes:

- Place for wegits
- Place for apps listing (menue)
- Access telephony functionality (call, phone history ...)
- Access settings.